# Discord.js / Javascript | How do we make bot send the same message with some filterS

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

For example

My message:

```js

Hello

```

I wanna make bot ignore **```js** and **```** and send the same message

Bot message:
Hello

Any javascript function to do this?

Comment: Please elaborate on your question. Do you want something that only ignores `\`\`\`js` and `\`\`\`` or also other filters? Show us what you have tried so far, what problems did you encounter, what is the actual issue you want fixed? Right now you seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

````js
message.channel.send(message.content.replace(/```(\w+\n)?/g, ''));
````

[image: pic]

Comment: Could you tell me what is string.prototype property? :3

Comment: [Object Prototypes - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes)